# how to disable order confirmation mail in a prestashop module?

Tags: prestashop-1.7

i want to create a payment module in prestashop and i would like to disable order confirmation mail when a customer validates his order. 
i have tried to override the Mail class but it affects the other mail sending. i do not know which file to override and  how to do it.
i saw somewhere we can also override PaymentModule but i don't know how to do it

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i succeeded to block mail sending by using this :
i use the **actionEmailSendBefore hook**
$this->registerHook('actionEmailSendBefore')

public function hookActionEmailSendBefore($params){

```
   if($params['template'] === 'order_conf'){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with create override/classes/PaymentModule.php (and clear cache).
In the override you must put the validateOrder function by commenting on the sending part of the email (to line 206)

Regards

Comment: i tried to override PaymentModule.php but i got this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$id_cart' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) inside the validateOrder parameters

Comment: i have this  code public function validateOrder(
        $id_cart,
        $id_order_state,
        $amount_paid,
        $payment_method = 'Unknown',
        $message = null,
        $extra_vars = array(),
        $currency_special = null,
        $dont_touch_amount = false,
        $secure_key = false,
        Shop $shop = null)

Comment: comment if (Validate::isEmail($this->context->customer->email)) {
                            Mail::Send(... in override PaymentModule

Comment: i commented the mail function but there's an error in the validateorder function parameters: Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '$id_cart' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)